# insert to a dynamic 2d array in c

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

im trying to insert a value to a dynamic 2d array of chars:

```
    theBoard->_board[row][col] = val;
```

but on each assignment of a char to (row,col), it also puts it on (row-1,col+8).
what could be the problem?

here's the allocation of the array:

```
    if ((new = (BoardP) malloc(sizeof(struct Board))) == NULL)
{
    reportError(MEM_OUT);
    return NULL;
}
if ((new->_board = (char**) malloc(rows * sizeof(char*))) == NULL)
{
    reportError(MEM_OUT);
    return NULL;
}
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    if ((new->_board[i] = (char*) malloc(cols * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
    {
        reportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }
```

when i'm inserting an 'X' and printing with:

```
BoardP b = createNewDefaultBoard();
b->_board[2][0] = 'X';
printBoard(b,0,0);
```

i'm getting this output:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0                                
1                            X   
2    X                           
3                                
4                                
5                                
6                                
7                                
8                                
9
```

Comment: Even though you are coding C, please avoid using "new" that is a reserved keyword in C++. Also, do you initialize memory after allocation (to avoid reading garbage)?

Comment: First: don't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: yes, i'm initializing the array.

Comment: The allocation seams to be good, show us the insert code, the values or row and col, etc.

Comment: I agree, the allocation is fairly standard

Comment: @TioPepe I added an example of the insert code. (the printBoard function gets the board and the row and col to start printing from)

Comment: do a 
printf("%p %p\n", &_board[2][0], &_board[1][8]); 
in order to check for memory wrapping (check if we are referring to the same memory location)

Comment: If you are allocating less than what you're thinking, I would expect a SegFault while accessing _board[9][9], for instance. But your printing function seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your board probably only has 8 columns. If you access column 8+ you will be reading (or writing) whatever is next in memory, which for all but the last row is the next row.

```
 <0,1> <0,2> <0,3> <0,4> <0,5> <0,6> <0,7>  --> 
 <1,0> <1,2> <1,3> <1,4> <1,5> <1,6> <1,7>  -->
 ...
```

Comment: basically the board is initilized to 10X10. when i'm inserting an 'X' to (2,0), it also appears in (1,8).

Comment: for example if you put a 'a' to <1,7> you can access it by using <0,15> . There is a simple array arithmetic here like this a[1][7] will be like (a + 1).8 + 7 => a[0][15] will be (a+0).8 + 15 all the same in the end.

Comment: Are you really really sure that `cols` is 10 and not 8? Because a value of cols between 5 and 8 is the most probable explanation to the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck both rows and cols are 10, I triple checked that.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me (with cols=10). Try printing `cols` before you allocate the rows to make sure it hasn't changed.